# How do I remove my item from the cart in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm generating my cart as such:

```
if( !is_wp_error( $this->getCartContentsCount() ) ) {
    $cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    foreach( $cart_items as $item ) { ?>
        <div class="left col-md-3">
            <div class="product-image"><!-- Make sure ot check if it's a gallery, if so, get its first image -->
                <?php echo $item['data']->get_image(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right col-md-8">
            <h4 class="product-name"><?php echo $item['data']->get_name(); ?></h4>
            <div class="product-information">
                <span class="product-quantity"><?php echo $item['quantity'] . 'x' ?></span>
                <span class="product-price"><?php echo $item['data']->get_price_html(); ?></span>
            </div>
            <?php
                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
                    '<a href="%s" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">X</a>',
                    esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $item ) ),
                    __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                    esc_attr( $item['product_id'] ),
                    esc_attr( $item['data']->get_sku() )
                ), $item );
            ?>
            </div>
    <?php }
}
```

As you can see, I'm using the basic Woocommerce implementation of the "remove item" mechanism as per `cart.php`, but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

This is what Woo generates:

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/cart/?remove_item%5Bkey%5D=6e7b33fdea3adc80ebd648fffb665bb8&amp;remove_item%5Bproduct_id%5D=807&amp;remove_item%5Bvariation_id%5D=0&amp;remove_item%5Bquantity%5D=1&amp;remove_item%5Bline_subtotal%5D=40&amp;remove_item%5Bline_subtotal_tax%5D=0&amp;remove_item%5Bline_total%5D=40&amp;remove_item%5Bline_tax%5D=0&amp;remove_item%5Bdata%5D&amp;_wpnonce=2242057dec" aria-label="Remove this item" data-product_id="807" data-product_sku="235677r">X</a>
```

I have checked every attribute and it is indeed valid!

Other symptoms:

1. The link, if accessed directly, takes me to the cart itself (I
   believe it is due to the nonce).
2. Dumping the cart before and after the click still shows the same
       cart with just one item in it, so the mechanism to delete doesn't
       work as the cart doesn't change its state.

How come it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I actually went ahead and copied the `cart.php` implementation and customized it to my needs:

```
ob_start();

if( !is_wp_error( $this->getCartContentsCount() ) ) { //This checks if there are any items in the cart.
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        $_product = apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_cart_item_product',
            $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key
        );

        $product_id = apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id',
            $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key
        );

        if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
            $product_permalink = apply_filters(
                'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink',
                $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key
            ); ?>

            <div class="cart-item <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
                <div class="left col-md-3">
                    <div class="product-image">
                    <?php
                        $thumbnail = apply_filters(
                            'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail',
                            $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key
                        );
                        if ( !$product_permalink ) {
                            echo wp_kses_post( $thumbnail );
                        } else {
                            printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), wp_kses_post( $thumbnail ) );
                        }
                    ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="right col-md-8">
                    <h4 class="product-name">
                    <?php
                        if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters(
                                'woocommerce_cart_item_name',
                                $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;'
                            );
                        } else {
                            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters(
                                'woocommerce_cart_item_name',
                                sprintf(
                                    '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
                                    esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_name()
                                ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key
                                )
                            );
                        }
                        // Meta data.
                        echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                        // Backorder notification.
                        if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
                            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters(
                                'woocommerce_cart_item_backorder_notification',
                                '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>'
                                )
                            );
                        }
                    ?>
                    </h4>
                    <div class="product-information">
                        <div class="product-quantity">
                        <?php
                            $product_quantity = sprintf(
                                '%s<input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="%s" />',
                                $cart_item['quantity'], $cart_item_key, $cart_item['quantity']
                            );
                            echo apply_filters(
                                'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity',
                                $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item
                            ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                        ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-price">
                        <?php
                            echo apply_filters(
                                'woocommerce_cart_item_price',
                                WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                        ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-remove">
                        <?php
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
                                '<a href="%s" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
                                esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                                esc_attr( $product_id ),
                                esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                            ), $cart_item_key );
                        ?>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
}

$markup_output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo $markup_output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use this `WC_Cart::remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );`